# PHP Cookie não é set em servidor remoto

Tags: php, cookies, set

Eu implementei um cookie que funciona no servidor local mas não funciona no server remoto, não percebo o porquê. Obrigado pelas eventuais ajudas. Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php


            if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])) {
                $firstName = ucwords($_POST['name']);
                setcookie('Cookie', $firstName, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);

                insertData($firstName);
                $last = mysqli_insert_id($db);

                ?>
<h1>Hello, <?php echo $firstName; ?>! How are you?</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
                            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value='' autofocus="autofocus">
                            <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $last; ?>">
                            <input name="name2" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>">
                            <button name='submit2' type="submit"></button>
                        </form>

<?php
}



else if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
            $mail = $_POST['email'];
            $last = $_POST['id'];
            $firstName = $_POST['name2'];
            updateData($mail, $last);

            ?>
<h1>Awesome, <?php echo $firstName; ?>. I’ll keep you updated.</h1>

<?php }




else if (isset($_COOKIE['Cookie'])) { ?>
<h1>Hi, <?php echo $_COOKIE['Cookie']; ?>. Welcome back.</h1>


<?php }




else { ?>
<h1>Hello, my name is Lisa.</h1>
<form id="form1" action="" method="POST">
                        <input id="name" name="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus">
                        <button id="button1" type="submit"></button>
                    </form>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Em seu `setcookie` você pode identificar o path e também o domínio, para que o cookie possa ser armazenado E também lido pelo seu servidor.

Possivelmente seja este o seu problema.

**path**

> O caminho no servidor aonde o cookie estará disponível. Se configurado
>   para '/', o cookie estará dosponível para todo o domain. Se
>   configurado para o diretório '/foo/', o cookie estará disponível
>   apenas dentro do diretório /foo/ e todos os subdiretórios como
>   /foo/bar do domain. O valor padrão é o diretório atual onde o cookie
>   está sendo configurado.

**domain**

> O domínio para qual o cookie estará disponível. Configurando o
>   domínio para 'www.example.com' fará com que o cookie esteja disponível
>   no subdomínio www e nos subdomínios superiores. Cookies disponíveis
>   para um domínio inferior, como 'example.com' estarão disponíveis para
>   subdomínios superiores, como 'www.example.com'. Browsers antigos ainda
>   implementam a » RFC 2109 e podem requerer um . no início para
>   funcionar com todos os subdomínios.

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 0):

Os cookies devem ser colocados no início da página, ele carrega antes de outros elementos.
No caso do seu código, crie uma `session_start()` e depois passe os dados no cookie.